# Accessing vue $ref returns undefined

Tags: vue.js

While accessing/operating on $refs in Vue, I am getting undefined.

```
<div ref="table-ref">This is sample ref</div>
```

Now in Vue method, I am trying to access the ref and add scroll to it

```
const tableRef = this.$refs['table-ref'];
tableRef.scrollLeft = tableRef.offsetWidth;
```

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you please share the rest of the `<template>` and `<script>` tag?

The loading state of a refs really depends from where it is called within a template (if it is within a slot or a v-ref) and from the syntax used (script setup, composition apo, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your codeblock within `this.$nextTick` to make it work

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
  const tableRef = this.$refs['table-ref'];
  tableRef.scrollLeft = tableRef.offsetWidth;
});
```